# output of kamailio shared memory

Tags: kamailio

I am trying to monitor the memory usage of kamailio. The PKG memory I have arranged, though the shared memory is something else.
According to documentation you can get the shared memory like this:

```
kamcmd mod.stats all shm
```

In my case, I get the following:

```
Module: core
{
        msg_lump_cloner(984): 1560
        dns_cache_mk_bad_entry(867): 192
        dns_cache_mk_rd_entry(1216): 232
        build_req_buf_from_sip_req(2155): 2752
        sip_msg_shm_clone(495): 822664
        tcpconn_new(957): 16416728
        counters_prefork_init(207): 30720
        cfg_clone_str(130): 208
        cfg_shmize(217): 976
        init_pt(105): 4200
        cfg_parse_str(906): 80
        init_pt(106): 16
        init_pt(111): 40
        create_avp(175): 10368
        register_timer(1012): 720
        cfg_register_ctx(47): 128
        init_tcp(4643): 8192
        init_tcp(4637): 32768
        init_tcp(4629): 8
        init_tcp(4622): 8
        init_tcp(4615): 8
        init_tcp(4609): 8
        init_tcp(4597): 8
        init_avps(90): 8
        init_avps(89): 8
        init_dst_blacklist(437): 16384
        init_dst_blacklist(430): 8
        timer_alloc(515): 96
        init_dns_cache(366): 8
        init_dns_cache(358): 16384
        init_dns_cache(351): 16
        init_dns_cache(345): 8
        init_timer(284): 8
        init_timer(283): 16384
        init_timer(282): 8
        init_timer(281): 8
        init_timer(270): 8
        init_timer(238): 8
        init_timer(221): 278544
        init_timer(220): 8
        init_timer(207): 8
        cfg_child_cb_new(830): 64
        sr_cfg_init(361): 8
        sr_cfg_init(354): 8
        sr_cfg_init(347): 8
        sr_cfg_init(335): 8
        sr_cfg_init(323): 24
        shm_core_lock_init(153): 8
        Total: 17660616
}
... [ list of modules here, snipped because not relevant I think] ...
```

So I guess the one I need is `Total: 17660616`.
However, what does this mean? Is it the total allocated memory? Available memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands you used is for seeing the used of shared memory per module.

If you want the statistics for total used and free shared memory, then use the command:

```
kamctl stats shmem
```

or:

```
kamcmd stats.get_statistics shmem:
```

The output will be like:

```
shmem:fragments = 179
shmem:free_size = 127471848
shmem:max_used_size = 7269016
shmem:real_used_size = 6745880
shmem:total_size = 134217728
shmem:used_size = 5106728
```

The **free_size** value is the one you have to monitor for available shared memory.